# Spring boot whitelist given IP addresses over https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am given multiple IPs which I have to whitelist over https only . I have set up the https via self signed certificate . code is like this :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebMvcSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure();


    }
}
```

I need to whitelist ip to given urls like `secure/dothis` , `secure/dothat`,`secure/dothisalso` . how to do this ?

I am using spring boot 1.5.x

Here is my ssl connector :

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatCustomizer {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createSslConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        try {
            File keystore = getKeyStoreFile();
            //File truststore = keystore;
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setPort(8443);
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
            protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
            protocol.setKeystorePass("password");
            //protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
            //protocol.setTruststorePass("password");
            protocol.setKeyAlias("demo");
            return connector;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "cant access keystore: [" + "keystore" + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
        }
    }

    private File getKeyStoreFile() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks");
        try {
            return resource.getFile();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            File temp = File.createTempFile("keystore", ".tmp");
            // FileCopyUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(temp));
            return temp;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: requiring https AND authorizing are 2 different things and thus have different configs. So you need both what you have here and a authorizerequests for the same pattern.Or (not sure if that works swithc the antMatcher and config . `http.antMatcher("/secure/**").... other config`.

Comment: @M.Deinum : can you please let me know how to configure both . so i can give it a try

Comment: Adding a section as mentioned in the answer should work. As both are in effect then. As stated you need both.

Comment: It is not working as i can access the url over http as well

Comment: Is security working in the frist palce? Also why are you asking the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906750/spring-boot-enable-http-and-https)?

Comment: I have deleted that question & Yes security is working at first place

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `http.authorizeRequests()` you can chain it with `hasIpAddress()` to whitelist ip's to access the given pattern from your `antMatcher`. This can then be chained using the `and()` to force a secure channel. For example:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasIpAddress("11.11.11.11").anyRequest().permitAll().and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Comment: These request must be on https only . They must not be accessible via http

Comment: You could try adding: .and().requiresChannel().antMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure()

Comment: I tried  : http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/**")
    .access("hasIpAddress('xxx.xx.xx.x') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1')").anyRequest().permitAll().and()
    .requiresChannel().antMatchers("/secure/**").requiresSecure(); still can access the url over http

Comment: Try to get the function to work seperatly first. Start with the secure one:         `http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**").permitAll().and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();`

This should atleast redirect you if you try to acces it with HTTP else we need to check your spring security configuraiton.

And then try the ipFilter after secure works. (without the secure part,) If that works combine them again.

Let me know which of the parts is not working and why.

Comment: still not working . I can still access the secure urls over http

Comment: should work. Are you sure there is no other SecurityConfigs configured? Are there no other path matchers fired before your matcher? (remove everything in your configure expect the requiresSecure)

If everything is in spring annotation you could try and put class level `@Order(1)` to make sure this class is used first.

Comment: There is only one line in security configuration